# Maximum data size that can be sent and received using sockets, at once?(TCP socket)

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, send, recv

I am designing a game which has master and multiple players. They send and receive data using TCP sockets.

Players transfer character strings between themselves via TCP sockets.The programs are being executed in red hat linux 6 os .

The character string transferred between players is of the type

```
char chain[2*hops+10];
```

The player code on sender side is

```
len = send(to,chain,sizeof(chain),0);
if (len != sizeof(chain)) {
perror("send");
exit(1);}
```

The code where player receives the data is like this :

```
char chain[2*hops+10];
len = recv(current,chain,sizeof(chain),0);
```

The value of hops is same for both the players.
For hops value till around 8000 it is working fine, but once the hops value crosses some point, the same program is not working. I believe data is not transferred in one go.
Is there a maximum buffer size for send and recv buffer?

Note:  The sockets between them are opened using this code:

```
s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
```

and then the usual connect and bind sockets on both sides.

Comment: @pranitkothari It is no such thing. Please don't post guesswork here.

Answer (score 5):

TCP is a *stream-oriented* protocol (as implied by `SOCK_STREAM`). Data that an application sends or receives (in [maximum-sized] chunks) is not received or sent in same-sized chunks. Thus one should read from a socket until enough data to be processed have been received, then attempt to process said data, and repeat:

```
while (true) {
    unsigned char buffer [4096] = {};

    for (size_t nbuffer = 0; nbuffer < sizeof buffer
                           ; nbuffer = MAX(nbuffer, sizeof buffer)) { /* Watch out for buffer overflow */
        int len = recv (sockd, buffer, sizeof buffer, 0);

        /* FIXME: Error checking */

        nbuffer += len;
    }

    /* We have a whole chunk, process it: */
    ;
}
```

You can also handle partial `send`s on the other side as described [here](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/multipage/advanced.html#sendall), much better than I ever would.

Comment: TCP supports send windows of over 1 billion bytes.  So you could use very large send buffers if your OS and network infrastructure can support it and your application needs it.

Comment: The TCP window has nothing to do with the behaviour the OP is trying to achieve. TCP is a _reliable stream service_, not a _reliable packet delivery_ system. For a good insight into the implications of this, I usually recommend [this post](http://blog.erratasec.com/2014/04/fun-with-ids-funtime-3-heartbleed.html) by Robert Graham.